# Emacs etags - How to ignore strings before function definitions

Tags: emacs, tags, etags

I will try to be specific. 
I'm writing a C code for a specific processor.
In my function definitions, I need to prepend the string:

> section("sec_name")

so my functions have the following structure:

```
section("sec_name") int function_name(){ .... }
```

This cause etags to not recognize them as a function and they are not included in the TAGS table.
Is it possible to tell etags to ignore the string

> section("sec_name")

and tag the following character as a function? 
Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

In manual page of etags is described the option `--regex=regexp`, where you can define your own regular expressions for making etags find tags based on non standard declaration format.

There are examples too.

Comment: Sorry i have tried etags --regex=/[ \t]*section\("\w+"\) \w+ \w+\(/     to include every line that starts with section("sec_name") int function_name( but i got the error: etags: null regexp